# Inequality between the coeficients of a quartic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials

Given the inequlity
$$
ax^4-bx-c\geq 0, \quad \forall x\in \mathbb R
$$
where $a, b$ and $c$ are real positive constants. Is it possible to conclude some inequality between the coefficients like $a\geq b$, $a\geq c$ or $a\geq F(b,c)$ for some positive functon $F$?

Comment: I guess you are assuming this is true for all $x\in \mathbb R$? You should edit your question with the range for $x$.

Comment: Indeed, this is impostant and if we take $x=b$ we get $a\geq \frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{c}{b^4}$. But I still wanted to find (if possible) a bound for a in terms only of $b$ or $c$.

Comment: Also, if this is true for all $x\in \mathbb R$, why are you looking for roots?

Comment: Ok, I edited my question.

Comment: If $c$ is positive, consider $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

This really requires calculus. First, write
$$
f(x) = ax^4 - bx -c
$$
we find that the derivative is $f'(x)=4ax^3 -b $ and the second derivative is
$f''(x)= 12ax^2$ so by the second-derivative test we need $a>0$, but that is clearly not enough. By solving the equation $f'(x)=0$, we find the critical point $x_0=\left(\frac{b}{4a}\right)^{1/3}$. Since by our choice $a>0$ the second derivative is nonnegative, the derivative $f'(x)$ is an increasing function so ther can only be one zero. By the derivative test, $f$ is decreasing for $x < x_0$ and increasing for $x>x_0$. So it is enough to require that $f(x_0) \ge 0$:
$$
a x_0^4 -bx_0 -c \ge  0 
$$
which after some manipulation gives the inequality
$$
    -3 b^{4/3} -\frac{c}{a} \left(4a\right)^{4/3} >0
$$
which together with $a>0$ is the solution.